# Move woocommerce tag description below products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We are trying to get our product **Tag** descriptions to the bottom of the page so the products show first.
I use this code for product category:

```
// move category description to bottom of pages
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description',woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

but this code not performed on product tag description.
how move product **tag** description from top of product to under on product?

Comment: Can you share the link to the website? It'll help analyze if the theme has hardcoded it or if it's based on the standard woocommerce template itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code, a single quote is missing in first line.

here is the correct code:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

it will be better if you move it after the main content wrapper ends by using

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 15 );
```